# Remote access to network share per wmic/ps1 : Access is denied

Tags: batch-file, cmd, share, wmic, ps1

I want to call (execute) a cmd or ps1 script remotely from one Windows 2016 Server 2016 on another. The problem is that script access to a `\\network-share` is denied.

**Reproduce**:

(1) a batch or ps1 script with specific Domain-User to `\\network-share` is successful:
`dir \\network-share` results in what it should.

(2) try to execute this script from another server via wmic or ps1 with the same user that has access to `\\network-share` `(wmic /node:"node" /user:"domain\usr" /password:"pwd" process call create "cmd.exe /c C:\temp\cmd.bat")`.
The cmd.bat contains: `dir \\network-share or dir \\<UNC-FQDN>\share or dir \\<IP>\share` and always gets „Access is denied“ although `domain\usr` itself has access to the `\\network-share`.

(3) the identical routine (2) with `dir C:\temp` runs like expected.

**Already tried** some registry keys, e.g.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies]
DisableLoopbackCheck
DisableStrictNameChecking
BackConnectionHostNames
LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy
```

Maybe one of those is needed on both machines and I did not try every option but to understand what might be the problem here could help I guess.

So, thx & Kind Regards :-)

Comment: Any hint, any information, any trial? No one knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I found two ways to overcome the problem:

a) using Sysinternals `PsExec.exe -u domain\user -p pwd -i \\node C:\temp\cmd.bat`
b) Create a Scheduled Task on the target machine that can be executed remotely by `C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /tn "name of the task" /s node /u domain\user /p pwd`

Maybe this will help somebody else.